# How to use array as meta_key in WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress

I need to use a timestamp string inside array below as meta key in WP_Query and I'm not sure how I can approach this.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(10) "1617112800"
}
```

Ideally I would like to use something like that but it doesn't work:

```
$todays_events = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'we_startdate'[0],
            'value' => time(),
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '>='
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Any directions much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us before the var_dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the postmeta is saved it is ran through maybe_serialize() which converts the array into serialized data, see below:

```
a:1:{s:3:"one";s:3:"two";}
```

Therefore, if you wish to you access the timestamp using such a query, I would suggest you store the meta value with its own key.